# Why the bootstrap styles are not applied even after the style css file is included?

Tags: html, css

I have linked the bootstrap css and js files in to my index.html. But the styling is not getting applied. 
Here is my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>



        <body>

        <input id=inputBox  style="min-width:50%;" type=text></input>
        <button id=submitButton class="btn-btn primary"  >Submit</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div >
        <table  class="table">
         <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Sender</th>
                      <th>Reciever</th>
                      <th>Group Code</th>
                      <th>Doc Type</th>
                      <th>PC</th>
                      <th>File</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
             <tbody id=renderOP>
             </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
        </body>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/elasticsearch.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jsrender.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/esmain.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Can anybody tell me what causes this problem?. When i replace the css files with url,it works. Also no custom css files are being taken from my css folder.

Comment: I would suggest that your relative URL to your stylesheet is probably incorrect.  Use the network tab in your dev tools to see what is not loading.

Comment: Presumably because you got the URL wrong. Look at your browser's Developer Tools' Net tab and check the request and response for the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you link and format is kind of perfect with the exception of the button tag which should be 
"class btn btn-primary".
Now I presume you are working on Ubuntu.I think you have forgotten to give permissions to the css files which are in that folder.
Set the folder permissions like
 "chmod -R 777 foldername"
 inside the parent folder in terminal and it would solve your issue.

Comment: Yeah. That was the issue there. I have copied the css file from another folder and it was being denied the permissions to access those.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
class="btn-btn primary"
```

to

```
class="btn btn-primary"
```

to make the button style work.